# Rspec Error: No Route Matches :show, :update, :create, :index (all actions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my rspec tests I'm having a problem that I don't think any of my other teammates are having. Each call to :show, :create, :update (all actions) comes up with this error:

```
Failure/Error: get :index ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/index".
```

Note: replace "index" with whatever action being called.

How can I debug this? Am I missing something that makes these methods available in my specs?

Comment: You haven't given nearly enough info to debug this problem. All your controller specs are returning exactly the same error (referring to `/index`)? Or do they give errors referring to the respective route? And when you refer to your teammates, do you mean that they are running the *same* tests and getting no errors? Routing can be difficult to debug so you'll have to provide more clues about what could possibly be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. I discovered in my app that somebody had overwritten the default behavior of the way that controller specs work. The question is really general about why controller action methods would not be available in a controller spec. The answer really is that they should be available in your controller spec unless you have overridden that functionality in some way.